# XSD Validaton keyref value not found for identity constraint

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd, keyref

I've got some troubles with XSD keyref validation which should run easily.
Here is my XML:

```
<Configuration>
    <Dependencies>
        <Dependency name="python"></Dependency>
    </Dependencies>
    <Plugins>
        <Plugin>
            <Dependencies>
                <Dependency name="python"></Dependency>
            </Dependencies>
        </Plugin>
    </Plugins>
</Configuration>
```

And now my Schema (please not the key.keyref pair in the Configuration element):

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Configuration">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:element name="Dependencies" type="DependenciesType"></xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Plugins">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:element name="Plugin" type="PluginType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:key name="kDependency">
            <xs:selector xpath="./Dependencies/Dependency"></xs:selector>
            <xs:field xpath="@name"></xs:field>
        </xs:key>
        <xs:keyref name="krPluginDependency" refer="kDependency">
            <xs:selector xpath="./Plugins/Plugin/Dependencies/Dependency"></xs:selector>
            <xs:field xpath="@name"></xs:field>
        </xs:keyref>

    </xs:element>

    <!-- Now the Dependencies types -->

    <xs:complexType name="DependenciesType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Dependency" type="DependencyType"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="DependencyType">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- And the plugin type -->

    <xs:complexType name="PluginType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Dependencies" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                        <xs:element name="Dependency" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:attribute name="name"></xs:attribute>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

The plugin dependencies name has to refer to Configuration dependencies name. I followed the tutorial here in order to check if I am not fool (http://zvon.org/xxl/XMLSchemaTutorial/Output/ser_keys_st5.html). I checked my XPath expression and they are good (https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html).

When I try to validate my XML file:

**Key 'krPluginDependency' with value 'python' not found for identity constraint of element 'Configuration'.**

I do not know where is the problem.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem but your XML file validates fine against the schema in oXygen 19. You might want to add details about which tool/parser you used when you get the error.

Comment: I used validator online like this (https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html) or this (http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/) but now you mention that it can be the tool used, some online tools are powered by JAXB engine which does not really support some keyrefs cases. I will try with lxml in python.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it was really ridiculous error.
In `PluginType` `Dependency` type, the attribute `name` needs a type. In my case, it is `type="xs:string"` and it works fine.